# Create copy of exe with different resource at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, exe

We'd like to offer our client the ability to make customised exes, based on ours, for their clients.

ie, basically the ability to make a copy of an exe with a different xml configuration file embedded in it. The "include it in the install" is not an option - we want this to look as if it was custom made for our client's clients.

I'm currently thinking of writing a dll at runtime including the resource (using an AssemblyBuilder), and then calling ILMerge to embed it in the final exe, but this is slightly more hackish than I would like.

So it's a tall-ask, but perhaps worth asking anyway: is there a .NET library which allows modifying a .NET exe's resources which could avoid the whole "dll holding a resource embedded by ILMerge" bit?

Or alternatively, is there a better approach to this which still meets the stated goals?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like alot of work to replace it once its already compiled. 
I would do it with a build script, a param, and different resource files.

Comment: Would this not require giving the client the full source code of the project?

Comment: no you need to get what resources you want to replace and have a resource file for each client. Store all your resources in a different folders ex. ClientA ... ClientB and when you are building for ClientA copy that resource file down from that folder before compiling

Comment: Nono, this is for our client's clients. As in once removed. Our client needs to be able to customise the program specific to their clients - different logos, different options, different wording. This is all easily doable via an xml doc, unfortunately at the moment I have to be the one to do it. We want our client to be able to do it. Slightly more complicated.

Comment: Just handle everything through the configuration file.  Have them handle creating a new setup.exe if they want.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not the approach I'd take with this problem there is a library allowing you to alter the embedded resources of a compiled executable, [Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil).

Embedding a resource with Cecil:

namespace inclusions:

```
    using Mono.Cecil; // supports both net and mono
```

embedding the resource:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string pathToExecutable = "Target.exe";

        byte[] encoding = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("<Data><!-- data goes here --></Data>");

        var resource = new EmbeddedResource(
               "ConfigurationFile", 
                ManifestResourceAttributes.Private, 
                encoding);

        var asm = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(pathToExecutable);

        asm.Modules.FirstOrDefault().Resources.Add(resource);

        asm.Write(pathToExecutable);
    }
```